# unable to run main.py from cmd line

Tags: python, package, modulenotfounderror

I'm working on the code for an "application". I've main.py in the "application" folder. Within "application" folder, in application\venv\Lib\site-packages , I've all the packages including psycopg2. I'm able to initiate the application execution from main.py when using PyCharm. But when initiating execution using "python main.py"  from cmd line , I get error -  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

To run from cmd line what do I need to do?

Comment: You must `activate` the virtual environment first.

Comment: Thanks Michael Butscher. I activated the virtual environment & it worked as expected.